# Quadratic Programming Solver Function in R

Tags: r, optimization, quadratic, quadratic-programming

I'm looking for a quadratic programming solver function to use in R. My matrix is symmetric positive semi-definite. My constraints are of the form Ax>=b and x>=0. I am working in RStudio version 3.3.1. I'm new to solving quadratic programming problems and R in general and would greatly appreciate any input.

So far I have tried:

- quadprog QP.solve, but my matrix is not positive definite
- sqlp but it won't download
- optisolve (quadfun) but it won't download
- Rcplex (Rcplex_solve_QCP)but it won't download

Please let me know if there are other functions that would possibly work. Thank you!

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html

Comment: @G.Grothendieck thank you for the link! I'll go through the list in it and see if any of them work.

Comment: CVXR comes with support for a few different solvers.